# regex for content not contained within anchor tags

Tags: php, regex, anchor

I'd like to run a `preg_replace` PHP function on a string but I need it to ignore anything inside anchor tags.

eg.

```
string = 'alpha beta delta gamma <a href="somelink.html">alpha beta delta gamma</a>'
to match = 'beta delta'
```

How would I get it to only pick up on the first instance of `beta delta` and not the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can negative lookahead for a closing tag:

```
preg_replace("/$to_match(?![^<]*<\/)/", 'foo', $string);
```

Also you shouldn't use regex on html.

Comment: Thanks, I popped an 'a' on the end & it worked a treat.

How come I shouldn't use regex on html? I'm processing some xmls to html, is that not recommended?

Comment: YW. I recommend reading this thread when you get free time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags